# How can a GRIB file be opened with pygrib without first downloading the file?

Tags: python, grib, pygrib

The [documentation](https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/index.html) for `pygrib` shows a function called `fromstring` which creates a gribmessage instance from a python bytes object representing a binary grib message. I might be misunderstanding the purpose of this function, but it leads me to believe I can use it in place of downloading a GRIB file and using the `open` function on it. Unfortunately, my attempts to open a multi-message GRIB file from NLDAS2 have failed. Does anyone else know how to use `pygrib` on GRIB data without first saving the file? My code below shows how I would like it to work. Instead, it gives the error `TypeError: expected bytes, int found` on the line `for grib in gribs:`

```
from urllib import request
import pygrib

url = "<remote address of desired file>"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

redirectHandler = request.HTTPRedirectHandler()
cookieProcessor = request.HTTPCookieProcessor()
passwordManager = request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passwordManager.add_password(None, "https://urls.earthdata.nasa.gov", username, password)
authHandler = request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passwordManager)
opener = request.build_opener(redirectHandler, cookieProcessor, authHandler)
request.install_opener(opener)

with request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read()
    gribs = pygrib.fromstring(data)
    for grib in gribs:
        print(grib)
```

Edit to add the entire error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\example.py", line 19, in <module>
    for grb in grbs:
  File "pygrib.pyx", line 1194, in pygrib.gribmessage.__getitem__
TypeError: expected bytes, int found
```

Edit: This interface does not support multi-message GRIB files, but the authors are open to a pull request if anyone wants to write up the code. Unfortunately, my research focus has shifted and I don't have time to contribute myself.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output. In the code you shared you’re still downloading the file yourself, no?

Comment: @AMC Either way I'm downloading the file, but I want to avoid saving it to disk. If I want it to work, I have to save it to disk then use `pygrib.open(filename)`

Comment: `pygrib.fromstring()` apparently works with a single GRIB message - it's not something you can iterate over.  You'd have to somehow split the retrieved data into individual messages (I have no idea how you'd do that), and call `.fromstring()` on them individually.

Comment: @jasonharper That's what I suspected but didn't want to believe. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look to https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib. It is the grib engine for xarray! From my point of view this is the state of the art of handling geospatial datasets.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by jasonharper you can use pygrib.fromstring(). I just tried it myself and this works.

Here is the [link](https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/) to the documentation.

Comment: It does not work for GRIB files with more than one message, so that rules out all the GRIB files from NLDAS2.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with pygrib v2.1.4, the changelog says that pygrib.open() now accepts **io.BufferedReader** object as an input argument.
[see pygrib changelog here](https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/blob/master/Changelog)

That would theoretically allow you to read a GRIB2 file from RAM memory without writing it to disk.

I think the usage is supposed to be the following :

> ```
> binary_io = io.BytesIO(bytes_data)
> buffer_io = io.BufferedReader(binary_io)
> grib_file = pygrib.open(buffer_io)
> ```

But I was not able to make it work on my side !

Comment: Cool find! It looks like those changes have not been released yet, but the pull request bringing in those changes does mention it must be an actual file on disk. https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/pull/206 Hopefully they expand that to include `io.BytesIO` and not just `io.BufferedReader`.